# How to use Serre duality to get the dual version of Kodaira vanishing theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

The Kodaira vanishing theorem state that if $L$  be a positive line bundle on a compact Kahler manifold $X$ then $$H^q(X,\Omega^p\otimes L) = 0$$
for $p+q >n$。

We have another dual version of it if $L$ is a negative line bundle then $$H^q(X,\Omega^p\otimes L) = 0$$ for $p+q <n$.

---

I stated a wrong version of the Serre duality, the correct version is as follows,and the proof of it is a direct consequence of the Hodge isomorphism theorem. together with some commutation relation.

The correct version is the pairing:

$$H^{p,q}(X,E) \times H^{n-p,n-q}(X,E^*) \to \Bbb{C}$$ is non degenerate.

Therefore to non degenerate pairing induce isomorphism $$H^{p,q}(X,E) \cong H^{n-p,n-q}(X,E^*)^*$$

Comment: its a duality between $H^p$ and $H^{n-p,*}$ !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{F}:= \Omega^p$. Let $\omega_X$ denote the canonical on $X$. Serre duality tells you more generally that $H^q(X,\mathcal{F}\otimes \mathcal{L}) \cong H^{n-q}(X,\mathcal{F}^*\otimes L^{-1}\otimes \omega_X)^*$.
Now $\mathcal{F}^* \otimes \omega_X \cong \Omega^{n-p}$ and $\mathcal{L}$ being positive tells you that $\mathcal{L}^{-1}$ is negative.

Comment: I don't know this Serre duality, does it follows the same idea as the original one? (which use analytic method to prove isomorphism of harmonic representation?)

Comment: this is the "standard" duality as in Hartshorn, maybe check Wikipedia to compare these results

Comment: because its a duality between $H^p$ and the dual of $H^{n-p}$!

Comment: thank you,  I will read the book to understand it better

Comment: I'm not very good in the analytic setting, but in the final paragraph "differential geometric theorem" of the wikipedia article on Serre duality they compare the analytic  and the geometric setup maybe that's helpful!